# apt-key fails behind proxy

Tags: networking, apt, proxy

Our company uses a filtering proxy which is setup correctly in /etc/environment and apt.conf.d
Regular internet access via http and https work but if I try to import a pgp key from keyserver.ubuntu.com it fails.

**Example:**

```
$ apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
gpg: requesting key A88D21E9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com  
gpgkeys: key 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9 can't be retrieved   
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

Support says, that they found that the keyserver is not accepting a HTTP/1.0 header (see below) although the HTTP/1.0 is a valid request.
So they say the problem is on the keyserver side and they are not willing to do anything on their side.
I cannot really judge if that is true and I can also not find any contact for the Ubuntu keyserver to get a statement from, so I am stuck.

**Trace gotten from zscaler proxy support :**

```
GET /pks/lookup?op=get&options=mr&search=0x36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9 HTTP/1.0  
Cache-Control: no-cache  
Pragma: no-cache  
Connection: Close  
X-Forwarded-For: 62.180.121.22*
```

Although this request is valid from RFC point of view, the server is denying it with a `400 Bad Request` error

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request  
Server: squid/3.1.19  
Mime-Version: 1.0  
Date: Mon, 09 Mar 2015 09:39:47 GMT  
Content-Type: text/html  
Content-Length: 3346  
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_URL 0  
Vary: Accept-Language  
Content-Language: en  
X-Cache: MISS from cassava.canonical.com  
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from cassava.canonical.com:11371  
Via: 1.0 cassava.canonical.com (squid/3.1.19)  
Connection: close*
```

Comment: Is virtual hosting enabled? check your squid config for the line http_port XXXX and add vhost behind it, if it is not there. Also the config of the squid server would be helpful. FYI squid 3.1.X is a reverse proxy with http1.0 whereas in >3.2.X this option has to be omitted, because starting with this squid version it's a reverse proxy with http1.1

Answer (score 0):

Since its an old post, I'll keep the answer short.
The apt-key command option "--recv-keys" uses a non HTTP/HTTPS port to access the key server. Thus it may fail in a firewall environment.

```
 apt-key --recv-keys 36A1D78           // may fail with firewall
```

A solution is to copy the actual GPG key manually into a textfile, say key.txt and use apt-key like this

```
sudo apt-key add key.txt
```

This will add the ascii key in binary form to the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg file. You can check if its there by

apt-key list|more

You shoudl see the key '36A1D78' listed. Fore the "actual GPG" key goto the launchpad.net webstite of the PPA and click on the "Signing key" link until you are in a page with the key in ASCII form.